# SQL DELETE warning

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have 2 tables in my database.

```
CREATE TABLE `Managers`(
`idManagers` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fullName` VARCHAR(100),
`address` VARCHAR(100),
`worksSince` DATE,
`salary` DOUBLE,
PRIMARY KEY (`idManagers`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `Sell` (
`idSell` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idManagers` INT,
`item` VARCHAR(100),
`price` DOUBLE,
`sellDate` DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (`idSell`),
INDEX `s1_idx` (`idManagers` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `s1`
FOREIGN KEY (`idManagers`)
REFERENCES `Managers` (`idManagers`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I needed to delete managers, that hadn't sold anything in 2013.
I came up with:

```
DELETE managers from managers join sell on sell.idManagers=managers.idManagers where NOT
YEAR(sell.sellDate) = 2013; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

It works fine, but I had to disable foreign key checks, because I had an error that I can't delete or update a parent row. I wonder, is there any way to do this without disabling foreign checks?

Comment: may be write a trigger and execute it before delete and delete the child data first, or use on delete cascade option to the constraint

Comment: So I have to drop the existing key, delete what I need, and add a new foreign key after deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete managers but keep earlier sales that they had, then remove the `foreign key` reference. You will have no relational integrity, between the tables. In other words, don't lie with your data structures.

Instead, you might consider adding a flag to the `managers` table to describe whether the manager is active or inactive. You can then update the flag based on recent sales and keep the foreign key reference.

Or, remove the managers from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to do this, depending on the situation:

Add 'ON DELETE CASCADE' to your foreign key constraint. This automatically deletes any child rows.

If you can't alter your database structure: simply do it in two queries, deleting the child rows first.

Think carefully if it's acceptable that child rows get deleted. Perhaps a better solution is to add something like an IsActive flag to your manager instead of deleting them.